# Rename keys depending on specific conditions

Tags: python

I have a problem to deal with my dictionary:

I have an initial dictionary (`dic_ONE`) with these 15 keys :

```
'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3', ...., 'key_15'
```

(but the total amount of keys can vary between 8 and 20)

I delete one or more of these keys if their values don't respect any conditions.
For example my final dictionary (`dic_TWO`) will be :

```
'key_2', key_5', ...., 'key_14'
```

(after deleting 4 keys : `key_1`, `key_3`, `key_4` and `key_15`).

But, and here is my problem, I now want to rename automatically every key left so as to have the numbers beginning at 1 (`dic_THREE`):

```
'key_1', ..., 'key_11'.
```

The value associated to `'key_1'` in `dic_THREE` will be the one associated to `key_2` in `DIC_TWO`. The value associated to `'key_2'` in `dic_THREE` will be the one associated to `key_5` in `DIC_TWO`, and so on.

Has someone an idea to do it?

Comment: please reformat your post. It is difficult to read a wall of text.

Comment: as for the code, what have you tried? You can simply iterate over the dict and assign the first key `key_1`, etc. However are the names actually `key_1, key_2, ... , key_15`?

Comment: As an aside, what you're trying to do would be easier with a list, if there's any way to refactor your code for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it and make sure 'key_2' comes before 'key_15'. I.e. you cannot just sort it alphabetically.

```py
import re

digits = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

def mixnum_key_func(string):
    result = digits.split(string)
    for i in range(1, len(result), 2):
        result[i] = int(result[i])
    return result

def mixval(keyval):
    mixkey, mixval = keyval
    return mixnum_key_func(mixkey)

def reorder(keydic):
    return {'key_'+str(n): v for n, (_, v) in enumerate(sorted(keydic.items(), key=mixval), 1)}
```

Test:

```py
dic_ONE = {'key_'+str(x):x for x in range(1,16)}

print(dic_ONE)

del(dic_ONE['key_4'])
del(dic_ONE['key_7'])

dic_TWO = reorder(dic_ONE)

print(dic_TWO)
```

Output:

```py
{'key_1': 1, 'key_2': 2, 'key_3': 3, 'key_4': 4, 'key_5': 5, 'key_6': 6, 'key_7': 7, 'key_8': 8, 'key_9': 9, 'key_10': 10, 'key_11': 11, 'key_12': 12, 'key_13': 13, 'key_14': 14, 'key_15': 15}
{'key_1': 1, 'key_2': 2, 'key_3': 3, 'key_4': 5, 'key_5': 6, 'key_6': 8, 'key_7': 9, 'key_8': 10, 'key_9': 11, 'key_10': 12, 'key_11': 13, 'key_12': 14, 'key_13': 15}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i don't really understand how it solves my problem.

Comment: @Tikre Then maybe I don't under stand your issue. I've rearranged my answer a bit. Then maybe you can elaborate on what I'm missing. Or if you don't understand it, I'll be happy to explain

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate step here for potential "gaps". Consider the made-up example where we only want to have values that are integers equal or greater than 100:

```
first_dict = {'key_1': 100, 'key_2': -100, 'key_3': 1000, 'key_4': 'abc', 'key_5': 101}

intermediate = sorted(
                [(key, value)
                    for key, value in first_dict.items()
                    if isinstance(value, int) and value >= 100],
                key = lambda x: x[0].split("_")[1])

intermediate = [("key_{}".format(index), value[1])
                for index, value in enumerate(intermediate, 1)]

output = dict(intermediate)
print(output)
```

This would yield

```
{'key_1': 100, 'key_2': 1000, 'key_3': 101}
```

While possible, consider refactoring your code instead to use lists in the first place. It does not make sense to have keys like "key_x" as they can appear unordered in a dict anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work if i have more than 9 keys (they will be ordered like this with your code: 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'key_2':32, 'key_3' : 43, 'key_27' : 43}
d = { 'key_' + str(k) : v[1] for k,v in enumerate(d.items(),1)}
print (d)
```

output:

```
{'key_1': 32, 'key_2': 43, 'key_3': 43}
```

Comment: Potential to fail when you get into multiple-digit numbers. For example, replace `key_7` with `key_27` in your example and check the results.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work if i have more than 9 keys (they will be ordered like this with your code: 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help ! After reading all of your first answers, i did this function which gives me the results i want :

```
def renomme_cles(dic):
    dic_renomme = {}
    liste_cles_dic = dic.keys()
    liste_numeros_dic = []
    for cle in liste_cles_dic :
        num_cle = cle.split('_')[-1]
        liste_numeros_dic.append(int(num_cle))
    liste_numeros_dic = sorted(liste_numeros_dic)
    l1 = range(len(liste_numeros_dic))
    l2 = []
    for i in l1 :
        l2.append(i+1)
    for num in liste_numeros_dic :
        old_cle = 'key_' + str(num)
        new_cle = 'key_' + str(l2[liste_numeros_dic.index(num)])
        dic_renomme[new_cle] = dic[old_cle]
    return dic_renomme
```